# Query on data exchange between web sites

Tags: web

All,

I have made my own website where the user enters his/her address. Based on the address, I am sending across the same information to various sites such as Foursquare, yelp to find all the information about the neighborhood. How should I go about technically implementing this feature(s)? This might be a broad question, but I really don't have en exp working on such development tasks.

Comment: This is indeed a too broad question I think... You may want to specify what you mean by "sending information" exactly. Are you just submitting some forms? That should be fairly easy. Making requests to the sites and scraping the data? Less easy, and usually forbidden.

Comment: No I meant only passing the address information to these sites. Then I would collect the information for the address entered on my site

Comment: which server side language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xml files can be generated to exchange text between websites..

twitter uses json, even you can use that.. there are plenty of tutorials online

[JSON Primer](http://www.json.org/js.html)